# Persistent URL Parameter

Tags: php

Is there a way to persist url parameters throughout the site as you click around? I'm working on a demo site which sets a url parameter on the first page to determine what's shown on the following pages. I would use session variables but the internal users are likely to share links between one another and the session wouldn't exist then. I've tried googling but all that returns are articles related to php frameworks like Cake. Is there a way to achieve this without using a framework?

Example of the Flow:

- Select Page > User selects Use Case and presses Submit to view Demo Site
- Inner Pages > Detect URL parameter and show data based on Use Case.
- As user clicks through the demo site the parameter persists so it shows the relevant data.
- When user returns to Select Page they can choose a new Use Case and repeat above actions.

Comment: There is no magic way. You need to manually append it to the query string of all links your code generates.

Comment: use a session value, but do not explicitly add the url parameter. this is not good practise, and is not a good user experience (keeping clean URLs is). session values are for logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a url parameter with the selection, and make sure it's always found in all internal links. I assume you don't want to do that because it's too many changes.

Some alternate ideas:

**IDEA 1:**

Save the initial selection inside the session or inside a cookie. Also add an optional url parameter for all pages, which also holds the selection. To avoid changing all of your internal links, check server-side if the selection url parameter was given. If it wasn't, redirect immediately to the same url, just with the url parameter added (according to the session/cookie). This way the url parameter will always appear without changing all the internal links everywhere, and users can still share links.

For implementation sake, let's assume our session variable is `$_SESSION['sel']` and that our optional URL parameter is `psel`. Let's assume all pages in the site are served via php. The following lines of php should appear in the top of all pages (can be placed in a separate php file and included in each page):

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['psel']))
{
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&psel='.$_SESSION['sel']);
  exit;
}
```

This is pseudo code, I'm on my iPad so excuse me if it's a bit short and not perfect. What this line does is check if the URL param is defined, and if not, redirect (to the same page) and define it according to our session variable. This way even if we have an internal link which doesn't include the URL param, this redirect will add it. There's a small bug regarding `?` in the request uri, I'll let you fix it.

This code does not change all of the internal links, all it does is the following: when an internal link is visited and the URL param is omitted (as it normally would), this code will stop the page from displaying without the param and redirect to the same page with the param.

Another important piece of code is to change our session variable in case the URL param was defined. This can be done by adding this else block to the code above:

```
else $_SESSION['sel'] = $_REQUEST['psel'];
```

This way, when the URL is shared by 2 users, it will always include the `psel` URL param and when the new user first visits it, it will set his session variable accordingly.

**IDEA 2:**

Create a "fake" directory for every selection. For example, let's say you site was http://example.com/index.php then you'll have http://example.com/sel1/index.php and http://example.com/sel2/index.php. These directories aren't real, and using .htaccess rewrites  (or even symbolic links in the FS) will actually point to the original files. Except, now you have this magic parameter in the path. This is useful because the path will remain the same through all relative links, meaning you don't have to change all internal links. If you need to access the current selection, you can easily get it by parsing the path of the current url.

This idea I think is a bit better because it achieves the same thing without redirects. It will be easiest to explain with a symbolic link, but keep in mind this can also be done with .htaccess rewrite rules. A symbolic link in Linux is a path that links to another path. If I run the following console commands (usually using SSH on my server):

```
ln -s . sel1
ln -s . sel2
```

It will create 2 directories inside . (the local directory), named sel1 and sel2, but they are just links to the original current directory. If this current directory is my web server document root, the effect is that accessing:

```
http://example.com/sel1/index.php
```

Will actually access:

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

Note that this isn't a copy of the directory. If I make changes to index.php or any other file in the local directory, these changes will also be reflected in `/sel1` and `/sel2`

How does this help? Instead of accessing my regular site, if I want to show selection 2 I will use the URL `http://example.com/sel2/index.php`. Because of the symbolic link, this URL will behave exactly like my original website `http://example.com/index.php`.

Now let's assume I want to check in php if I'm showing selection 2 or not, I can simply examine the variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and see if it includes the path `/sel2` or not.

This path will remain persistent between all internal URLs because they are usually relative.

Comment: The htaccess rewrites are a bit over my head but trying to understand option 1. Can you elaborate a bit more? And just to clarify a bit more on my part - If the user comes to a page and it has a url_param then I need to somehow append that parameter to all urls on the page without adjusting their code. (there's tons of links on these pages)

Comment: I elaborated a bit on both solutions. Both solutions avoid the requirement of changing the tons of internal URLs. I actually prefer the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a solid idea - I'm going to go with Idea2.

Comment: Great, if something isn't working, I'll be happy to follow through, just let me know :)

Comment: @talkol can you please show us a simple code on how you would do IDEA #2 in htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

What you describing are cookies, but they do not appear in URL.

For your usecase, best solution is path prefix in URL and relative links, as talkol describes in his second idea. It will not require any extra work on server side as long as you keep links relative.

Second option you have is using output buffering URL rewriter (see [output_add_rewrite_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.output-add-rewrite-var.php)), parsing produced output from applicatin and replacing links. But it is a bit stupid approach. It would be reasonable when you have large application and do not want to modify it.

All other ways are about generating links in PHP using your special function or that in framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best solution would be to store their initial selection inside of a `$_SESSION` variable, and then simply append that variable to the URLs throughout your site's structure, for example:

```
$url = (isset($_SESSION['use_case'])) ? $_SESSION['use_case'] : 'default';
echo 'my-page.php?use_case='.urlencode($url);
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are tons of urls in this demo site. I need something that can automatically append that parameter. I'm now thinking maybe just do it through js? Grab all anchors append the parameter..

Comment: I'd avoid JS if possible. Never rely on client-side scripting, as it can be disabled by the user and then the functionality of your site cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a case based problem you can set the case on $_SESSION and simply use a switch for each case.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php